# how to group by string pattern (not necessarily regex) in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a dataset in the collection with following schema:

```json
[
    {"status": "Completed", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Completed", "datetime_field": "2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "New", "datetime_field": "2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Cancelled - type 0", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Draft", "datetime_field": "2021-01-03T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Completed", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Cancelled - type 1", "datetime_field": "2021-01-04T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Cancelled - type 2", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Deleted", "datetime_field": "2021-01-05T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Completed", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"},
    {"status": "Completed", "datetime_field": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "aother_field_key": "aother_field_values"}
]
```

And I want to group by both `datetime_field` and `status` fields in mongoDB aggregation pipeline. I know that for the datetime field using `$dateToString` operator can easily control the granularity of grouping by datetime. The issue I'm having is to group by the `status`.

As you can see there are more than one type of **`Cancelled`** status, if simply do `{$group: {_id: {status: '$status'}}}` it will separate the different types of `Cancelled`, is there a way to group all different types of `Cancelled` into one group?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `$split` for ` - ` in your status and than `$cond` to check if they have same status than push them into `Cancelled` array

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use:  _id:{$substr: [ "$status", 0, 9 ]} in   $group stage